# Output goes stray at START and at END of a java loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, while-loop

I am writing a code for translating Signals from one form  to another form. 
My code works well but fails for the ends.

```
INPUT: String [] test = {"B","100","B","B","2","3","100","B","200","B","3","17","B","10" };
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:        B/101  B/1  B/106  B/201  B/21 B/11

GOT OUTPUT:        B/1  B/101  B/1  B/106  B/201  B/21

Comparison of Required Output and got output
         The first term B/1 is not required in got output.
         B/11 is missing at the end in the required output.

ALGORITHM:      "B" is replaced by "B/", and followed by addition of numbers appearing in Strings like "2", "3","100" which gives 105 and "1"
 is to be added for "B" hence 106 and final result becomes 'B/106'.

I am new comer to java and programming. I need help to get the required output.

This is my code:

```
public class SignalConversion { 

public static void main(String args[]) {

String [] test  ={"B","100","B","B","2","3","100","B","200","B","3","17","B","10" };

int i=0; int x=test.length;

String netSignal="";
int total=0;

while(!(x==0)){

        StringBuilder sb_matra= new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb_sur= new StringBuilder(); 

        if(!test[i].equals("B")) {   

            total=total+(Integer.valueOf(test[i])); 
        }
        else {
            total=total+1;
            sb_sur.append(test[i]+"/"+Integer.toString(total)+"  " );
            total=0; 
        } 

        netSignal=sb_sur.toString()+sb_matra.toString();

        System.out.printf(netSignal);   
        i++;
        x--;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are counting numbers first and then print B.

Answer (score 1):

When you encounter a "B", you should start summing the numbers following it, but only output the result when you encounter the next "B". That's why you have a problem at the ends. You print the first "B" when you encounter it, before calculating the number that should come with it.

Similarly, at the end of the loop, you should add an additional B with the last sum.

Here's a potential way of doing it (I think this loop is simpler than yours):

```
StringBuilder sb_sur= new StringBuilder(); 
boolean first = true;
for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if(!test[i].equals("B")) {   
        total=total+(Integer.valueOf(test[i])); 
    } else {
        if (!first) {
          total=total+1;
          sb_sur.append("B/"+Integer.toString(total)+"  " );
          total=0; 
        }
        first = false;
    }  
}
total=total+1;
// account for the last B
sb_sur.append("B/"+Integer.toString(total)+"  " );
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this way,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = { "B", "100", "B", "B", "2", "3", "100", "B", "200",
            "B", "3", "17", "B", "10" };

    boolean foundB = false;
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){

        if(foundB){
            if(test[i].equals("B")){
                System.out.print("B/"+(total+1)+" ");
                total=0;
            }else{
                total += Integer.parseInt(test[i]);
            }

            if(i==(test.length-1)){
                System.out.print("B/"+(total+1)+" "); // The last B
            }
        }
        if(test[i].equals("B")){
            foundB = true; // start counting only after you find a B
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i see Eran has made nearly the same attemp.

```
    String[] test = { "B", "100", "B", "B", "2", "3", "100", "B", "200", "B", "3", "17", "B", "10" };

    List<String> resultTest = new ArrayList<>();
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && test[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            resultTest.add("B\\" + (value + 1));
            value = 0;
        } else {
            if (!test[i].equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                value += Integer.parseInt(test[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    resultTest.add("B\\" + (value + 1));
    resultTest.forEach(System.out::println);
```